# import mysql DB from .sql setting default table to MyISAM

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I need to convert a MyISAM latin 1 DB into a MyISAM utf8 db

following another question I exported my DB without any encoding specification

```
mysqldump -uroot -p --skip-opt --set-charset --skip-set-charset mydb > mydb_utf8.sql
```

changed my DB to default charset utf8

now I need to specify on import that i want MyISAM tables ( default setting is InnoDB )

```
mysql -uroot -p --default-character-set=utf8 --default-storage-engine=MyISAM mydb < mydb_utf8.sql
```

--default-storage-engine=MyISAM give me this error "mysql: unknown variable 'default-storage-engine=MyISAM'"

Comment: --default-storage-engine looks like its a mysqld startup option not a mysql start option.. Open your SQL file with a text editor and on the top `SET default_storage_engine=MyISAM`;

Comment: it works if you answer i approve it as correct

Comment: ok done posted the comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

--default-storage-engine looks like its a mysqld startup option not a mysql start option..

Open your SQL file with a text editor and on the top

```
SET default_storage_engine=MyISAM;
```